# How can I Forecast One Variable Multiple Times by One Script in R?

Tags: r, model, rstudio, forecasting, ets

Suppose you have a data set that looks like this:

```
|Month|Food|Sales|
|01|Apple|1564|
|02|Apple|1323|
....
|12|Apple|1645|
|01|Banana|2158|
```

... that continues on a pattern all the way to "Zucchini".

So lets say you would like to forecast the sales in R as such:

```
ets <- forecast(ets(data))
```

How can I forecast, each of values in the "Food" column, in such a way that it will give me all of their forecasts separate?

Currently, I'm sub setting my data to only look at "Apple" and make a forecast. Then, I have to go back and change my sub setting data to "Banana" and make a forecast. I would like for each of their outputs separate, so that I may export them into Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom function that takes the name of a fruit and performs all the steps needed for a forecast, and then `apply` that function to a list of all the fruits you know. I have a code example here, but be aware that you may need to change lots of things based on your specific circumstances.

First, some data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  month = rep(1:12, times = 5),
  fruit = rep(c("Apple", "Banana", "Citrus", "Date", "Elderberry"), each = 12),
  sales = runif(12*5, min = 100, max = 10000)
)
```

Next, I want to create a custom function. In this case, the only argument I have is the type of fruit. I might want to add more arguments such as "how long do I want my forecast to be", etc. Note that this function returns the entire `forecast` object - you might want to select, for example, the `fitted` part of the model.

```
forecast_custom <- function(selected_fruit) {
  df_sub <- subset(df, fruit == selected_fruit)
  ts_sub <- ts(df_sub$sales)

  forecast(ets(ts_sub))
}
```

I can run this function by telling it which fruit to forecast:

```
forecast_custom("Apple")
```

I can also use something out of the `apply` family to run it over all types of fruit at once.

```
lapply(unique(df$fruit), forecast_custom)
```

If you want, you can also use a `map` function from the `purrr` package instead of `lapply` or `sapply`. The `map` function are a bit more strict about what goes in and what comes out. For example, it would be easier to generate a nice-looking data frame using `purrr`:

```
forecast_custom <- function(selected_fruit) {
  df_sub <- subset(df, fruit == selected_fruit)
  ts_sub <- ts(df_sub$sales)

  data.frame(
    fruit = selected_fruit,
    month = 13:24,
    forecasted_sales = as.numeric(forecast(ets(ts_sub))$fitted)
  )
}

> map_df(unique(df$fruit), forecast_custom)
#>         fruit month forecasted_sales
#> 1       Apple    13        4781.3679
#> 2       Apple    14        4781.3330
#> 3       Apple    15        4780.8736
#> 4       Apple    16        4781.2790
#> 5       Apple    17        4781.3523
```

Comment: So I've followed your approach and found it to work very well. My only question is, for the forecast_custom piece of your code, why are there only 10 results showing? These 10 results are forecasting the next 10 months, but I would like to extend this to 12 in order to show a full year's forecast. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a parameter of the `forecast` function that you can specify. The standard setting for `h` is 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple forecast by using the [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) functions in R and the [levels](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/levels.html) function which finds the unique values of the fruit type.

Then you create a "forecast function" which slices the input data frame [DF] based on the fruit type [Fruit] as seen in the code below to forecast for the specific input fruit. The function returns a ets forecast object.

```
library(forecast)
DF <- data.frame(month = rep(seq(1,12,by=1),3),
                 fruit = c(rep("apples",12),rep("banana",12),rep("orange",12)),
                 Sales = sample(0:1000, 12*3))


forecastFruit <- function(Fruit, inputDF)
{
  timeSeries <- ts(inputDF[inputDF$fruit == Fruit,]$Sales)
  forecast(ets(timeSeries))
}

Forecast <- lapply(levels(DF$fruit), forecastFruit, inputDF = DF)


plot(Forecast[[1]])
plot(Forecast[[2]])
plot(Forecast[[3]])
```

The output from the lapply will then by list of three objects from the forecast ets.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!